# Importar Excel .xls a Genexus por procedimiento

Tags: excel, while, genexus, importación

es la primera vez que estoy con **Genexus 18 Trial** e intento crear un procedimiento sencillo para poder leer **.xlsx y .xls** y pasar su contenido a la base de datos de una transacción.

```
&ExcelDocument.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\prueba.xlsx")

Do 'CheckStatus'
&CellRow = 1
&FirstColumn = 1
Do while not &ExcelDocument.Cells(&CellRow,&FirstColumn).Text.isEmpty()
    msg("Entra en el dowhile")
    &Concejo= New()
    &Concejo.ConcejoName = &ExcelDocument.Cells(&CellRow, &FirstColumn + 1).Text
    if &Concejo.Insert()
        commit
        msg("OK")
    endif
    &CellRow += 1
enddo

&ExcelDocument.Close()


Sub 'CheckStatus'
    If (&ExcelDocument.ErrCode <> 0)
        &ErrorMessage = &ExcelDocument.ErrDescription   
        &ExcelDocument.Close()
    Endif
Endsub
```

Mi principal problema es que no llega a entrar en el **do while**, como si la casilla en el documento estuviera vacía (tiene un HolaMundo) o no reconociese la condición. Desconozco si falta algo o lo realizo de la manera incorrecta. No consigo hallar respuesta en la documentación oficial.

Gracias de antemano.

**EDIT:** He conseguido que **funcione para los .xlsx** incorporando el siguiente código donde `&ExcelBlob` es de tipo Blob y `&File` de tipo File

```
&File.Source = &ExcelBlob
If (&File.ErrCode <> 0)
        msg(&File.ErrDescription)
Endif
&ExcelDocument.Open(&File.GetURI())
```

Ahora me lee y me importa correctamente archivos .xlsx pero **no funciona con los .xls**, los cuales necesito leer también. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Parece estar correcto el programa. 
Lo que no estoy viendo es cómo manejas el error en el open. Es decir, si da error el open te puede pasar que no entre en Do while.
Podria dar error por permisos (ahi importante saber el lenguaje que estás generando).

De pronto lo mejor es generar log e incluso usar la LogApi en vez del message para ver que puede estar pasando e incluso te queda para cuando esté en producción poder "loggear" en caso de problemas: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?37872,Log+external+object#Web

Comment: Utilizo la versión Trial así que genera .NET, no es posible leer xlsx en este lenguaje?

Comment: Entendi. Es correcto. Si estás usando la trial entonces se despliega a la nube (ej: trialapps3.genexus.com o similares) y desde una aplicación en esa nube no puedes acceder a un excel local en tu máquina (C:\Users\user\Documents\prueba.xlsx)

Comment: He conseguido solucionarlo en parte utilizando variable de tipo Blob y de tipo File, lee los .xlsx pero no consigo que lea los .xls